# Various effects of prednisolone

Tags: blood-pressure

I've just been given a prednisolone treatment after widsom tooth extraction (on local anaesthetic). I'm on 40mg per day, aside with 3g of amoxicillin per day. I weigh about 62kg

I've read the prednisolone leaflet, just to be sensible.
I found in it two things that disturb me :

- (1) It can come up positive in doping control
- (2) It raises blood pressure

My questions, relative to each of these facts, are :

- (1a) Does this mean that if I do sport my performance will be artificially enhanced
- (1b) Am I at risk of harming myself by overdoing it (heart or whatever) ?
- (1c) If I run say for one hour assuming the last twenty minutes were only achieved thanks to the drug, does it still contribute to keeping me fit as much as an ordinary one hour jog ? In other words is there any point in trying to keep fit during the treatment ?
- (2a) If I don't suffer from high blood pressure, can the treatment raise my blood pressure to an unhealthy level ?
- (2b) On short term, does it raise blood pressure like when you treat yourself to a salty takeaway or does it do it to a higher degree ?